# Applying Logic to Sets of Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to add logic that calculates price per claim. Below, there are two claims, one for patient 5, and another for patient 6. Original idea is to create a unique list of patient numbers in a separate table, then sort the original table by these unique patient numbers and run conditional statements to output a single value (reimbursement value).Then iterate through the unique table until completed. Does this sound like a feasible workflow? Not necessarily looking for specific code but more of a workflow/process

For example/context:

| PatNo | RevCode | CPT | BilledCharges | DRG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 141 | null | 100 | 880 |
| 5 | 636 | J1234 | 50 | null |
| 6 | 111 | null | 8000 | 783 |
| 6 | 636 | J1234 | 300 | null |

PSYCH look up table: if claim has DRG on table then calculate 75% of BilledCharges for claim.

| **DRG** | **Service Category** |
| --- | --- |
| 876 | PSYCH |
| 880 | PSYCH |
| 881 | PSYCH |
| 882 | PSYCH |
| 883 | PSYCH |
| 884 | PSYCH |
| 885 | PSYCH |
| 886 | PSYCH |
| 887 | PSYCH |

C- Section look up table: if claim has DRG on table pay $5000 for claim.

| DRG | Service |
| --- | --- |
| 765 | C-SECTION |
| 766 | C-SECTION |
| 783 | C-SECTION |
| 784 | C-SECTION |
| 786 | C-SECTION |
| 787 | C-SECTION |
| 785 | C-SECTION |
| 788 | C-SECTION |

If claim has RevCode 636, then add 50% of charges to claim reimbusment.

OUTPUT:

| PatNo | Reimburs. |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 100 |
| 6 | 5150 |
|  |  |

Comment: You need to clarify what you mean by "apply logic to sets" - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Its very unlikely you need to do any painful row by row operations (i.e. iterations) you will almost certainly be able to do everything in a single query **BUT** we need to see sample data and expected results to help with that.

Comment: It seems the service category table is not necessary for this? Have you had a go? Its a fairly straight forward query... with conditional sums... what are you stuck on?

Comment: What if a claim has DRG *AND* RevCode 636?

Comment: `8000 * 0.75 = 6000`? Not 5000?

Comment: You need to explain the relationships between your tables - are they as per the answer below? Are they even needed for your logic?

Comment: When you edited your question, you removed half of the Psych table, and the explanation about reimbursing $5000 for sections.

Comment: So is the psych lookup table and the c-section lookup table the same i.e. a DRG table? or 2 tables?

Comment: @DaleK I'm giving up, time for bed. Good luck! Steal, edit or delete my answer as you see fit to help the op best :)

Comment: Y'all: Thank you for the help! I'm pretty new to SQL and just know basics so it is appreciated. There is a hierarchy in insurance claims and it get's very, very convoluted. DRG's take priority and you get the drg rate and then if you have rev code 636 you get 50% of the charges for that line. I was more thinking of a general workflow and I think I have that. My main concern was outputing just the unique patients but I guess I can group by the patient number as Mat did below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...

Patient 5's reimbursement is...(75% of 100) + (50% of 50) = 100

Patient 6's reimbursement is...(5000) + (50% of 300)

Assuming you've told us all the rules...

You can left join the tables, to check if values are present there or not, then use case expressions to apply the logic, and finally aggregate it to sum it all up...

```
SELECT
  YourTable.patno,
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN section.drg IS NOT NULL THEN 5000
         WHEN psych.drg   IS NOT NULL THEN 0.75 * yourTable.billedcharges
         WHEN yourTable.revcode = 636 THEN 0.5 * yourTable.billedcharges
         ELSE 0
    END
  ) 
FROM
  yourTable
LEFT JOIN
  section
    ON section.drg = yourTable.drg
LEFT JOIN
  psych
    ON psych.drg = yourTable.drg
GROUP BY
  yourTable.patno
```

Please forgive typos, I'm on my phone.

Comment: @DaleK The op messed up the edit to their question. This WAS in the question when I started typing... `C- Section look up table: if claim has DRG on table pay $5000 for claim.` (I can see it in the question's edit history.)